# Code in assembly to copy the contents of source array to target array

Tags: arrays, assembly, masm, irvine32

Following is my code in assembly to copy the contents of source array to target array .But  it seems that all contents of  source array are not copied to target array.Please help.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
mess1 byte "YOUR ARRAY IS:",0
mess2 byte "COPIED Array is:",0
source byte "YOU Have to work hard to score a 4",0
target byte sizeof source dup(0)

.code
main PROC
call clrscr
call crlf

mov edx,offset mess1
call writestring
call crlf

mov edx,offset source
call writestring

call crlf
call crlf
mov ecx,sizeof source
L1:
mov esi,0
mov al,source[esi]
mov target[esi],al
inc esi
loop L1

mov edx,offset mess2
call writestring
call crlf
mov edx,offset target
call writestring

    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

OUTPUT:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you walked through the code in a debugger?

Comment: Try and document/comment your code. That will help you solve the problem.

Comment: We expect you to show your effort to solve your problem. Please take a look at the Help Center.

Comment: @black seems to me that there is a reasonable attempt to do the copy with just one bug.

Comment: @MichaelPetch With 'problem' I meant fixing bugs, not solving the primary request. It's a specific category of off-topic questions.

Comment: I don't agree. Short of him saying "I debugged this, but can't figure it out". Seems to me this question is on topic. The only addition to the question I would have made is providing information about what was or wasn't copied vs expected result. I mean I looked at it, understood the problem, saw the bug, and clearly zx485 did too.

Answer (score 5):

Move the `MOV ESI,0` out of the loop in this part of your code

```
call crlf
call crlf
mov ecx,sizeof source
L1:
mov esi,0          ; <-- move one line up
mov al,source[esi]
mov target[esi],al
inc esi
loop L1
```

It should look like

```
call crlf
call crlf
mov ecx,sizeof source
mov esi,0
L1:
mov al,source[esi]
mov target[esi],al
inc esi
loop L1
```

Otherwise you reset `ESI` to zero in every loop, rendering the `INC ESI` useless.

Comment: `rep` family could be used too.

Comment: @Nouraiz Hussain: I don't want to be impolite, but if my answer solved your problem, you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

if you loop to L1 this way, you always reset your esi register, and copy the first byte cx times. so move the "mov esi,0" OUTSIDE of the loop

```
    ...

    mov esi,0
L1:
    mov al,source[esi]
    mov target[esi],al
    inc esi
    loop L1
```

Comment: Not sure how this provides any more information that the first answer given.